# Actionbar settings not displaying

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, android-settings

I am having an issue that my Settings button in my action bar is not displaying.  The Menu button that I made is displaying fine, but there is nothing to the right of it (where the 3 dots are suppose to be).  Anybody know if I did something wrong for it to not display?  I can see it in the menu.xmp, but when I run it, it is not there.

this is my menu.xml (my.xml):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyActivity" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_menu"
        android:title="Menu"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

Inflating Menu Here:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of where you inflate the menu?

Comment: Does your test device have a hardware menu button?

Comment: Yes, its a Galaxy S4.  If by that you mean the button on the bottom left that opens the settings menu lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devices with hardware menu buttons, such as the Samsung Galaxy S4 you are using to test your app, will never show the 3-dot menu button in the `ActionBar`/`Toolbar`. This is the expected behavior, as the hardware menu button negates the need for a software button. Any devices without a hardware menu button will display the 3-dot menu button as they should.